# Google Cloud Messaging single request

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I've been searching over the web but I can't seem to find some straight answer.
I've got an application developed and now I need to add it notifications. My issue is that I need each device to be unique and send each one of them a different notification. (I don't mean ONE UNIQUE notification) but I mean to send some users a notification and others don't.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

As a part of the GCM infrastructure, you will need to have your own web application that will allow individual instances of your app to register. When this happens, your Android application will pass to the web application a registration ID along with any additional information that you can use to identify the device. Once you have this information stored, you can pick and choose which device should receive your notification.

See: Architectural Overview section in the http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html